# Why I am not getting a long equation in a continuous way in next line?

Tags: equations

The Code of my equation is as follows:

```
\begin{equation}

\frac{d^2f_0}{d\xi^2} + \frac{1}{f_0} (\frac{df_0}{d\xi})^2= \frac{n!}{(m+n)!(2n+m+1)}\frac{1}{f^3} \left[\frac{(m+n)!}{n!} (-2n-m+1)+ (2n+m)^2  I_1 +4(m+n)^2 I_2-4(m+n)(m+2n) I_3+\frac{ \beta E_{00}^2 {2f_0^3} \left[\frac{\omega_{p0} r_0}{c}\right]^2 exp(\xi/d) I_4]\right

\end{equation}
```

I am no getting this equation in a continuous way. Latex does not break the equation to continue it. When I run the program only half of the equation is visible to me. I tried so many tricks but not getting the full equation. What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Latex does not split equations automatically. You can find how to do it in [The Not So Short Introduction to Latex](http://tug.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf). The section 3.4 is completely dedicated to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you maybe looking for something like the following solution, which employs a `split` environment to break the long equation across four rows? (Note that I encountered three syntax errors in the code you posted. I hope I applied appropriate fixes.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\frac{d^2f_0}{d\xi^2} + \frac{1}{f_0} \biggl(\frac{df_0}{d\xi}\biggr)^2\\
&\quad= \frac{n!}{(m+n)!\,(2n+m+1)}\frac{1}{f^3} 
  \biggl[\frac{(m+n)!}{n!} (-2n-m+1)\\
&\qquad+ (2n+m)^2  I_1 +4(m+n)^2 I_2-4(m+n)(m+2n) I_3\\
&\qquad+ \frac{ \beta E_{00}^2} {2f_0^3} \Bigl[\frac{\omega_{p0} r_0}{c}\Bigr]^2 
  \exp(\xi/d) I_4]\biggr]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You @Mico. This is exactly what I want.